# |Aut(G)| dependent on orders of elements of G?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, group-isomorphism

I'm trying to prove a theorem, but I feel completely stuck. Is it true that if all elements of $G$, which is abelian, have order less than or equal to $2$, then $|Aut(G)|$ must be odd? And if so, then could you please provide with some insight? Once I get this I will probably be able to move further with my theorem.

Comment: It should probably be noted that such a group is: 1. Necessarily abelian, and 2. Isomorphic to a direct sum of copies of $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$. Moreover, we can view such a group as an $\mathbb F_2$-vector space, and a group homomorphism between two such groups is the same thing as a linear map between the two. So this is really a linear algebra problem.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that it is abelian. But I still don't get how the correlation with the order of $Aut(G)$ comes about.

Comment: An automorphism of $\displaystyle\bigoplus_{i=1}^n \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ is the same thing as an element of $GL_n(\mathbb F_2)$. So this problem comes down to counting the elements of $GL_n(\mathbb F_2)$.

Comment: I appreciate your hint, but we haven't yet covered fields (it's going to be a separate course, actually). But I guess there's nothing difficult in your notation, as soon as I get what $\mathbb{F}_2$ means. I don't have in-depth familiarity with direct products either, so it is probably the case that this can be proved in a different way.

Comment: $\mathbb F_2$ is just another name for $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, which places an emphasis on the fact that the latter is a field. That is, $\mathbb F_2 = \{\overline 0, \overline 1\}$ with addition and multiplication defined modulo $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since every non-trivial element of $G$ is of order 2, then by the Cauchy's theorem $G$ is of order $2^n$ for some $n$. Then you should prove that $Aut(G)$ is isomorphic to $GL(n,2)$, the group of all binary $n\times n$ matrices. The order of this group equals $(2^n -1)(2^n-2)(2^n-4)...(2^n-2^{n-1})$. For example if $n=2$ then it would be just Alan's example and $|Aut(G)| = 6$. I think you can easily see that this number is odd if and only if $G \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Answer (score 4):

This is not true.  The Klein 4 group has all elements of order 2 or 1, but the automorphism group of the Klein 4 group is $S_3$ which has order 6

Comment: Then would it be true that if there is at least one element of order greater than $2$ in $G$ then $|Aut(G)|$ must be even?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention in my initial question that $G$ is abelian.

Comment: @sequence: yes. In that case $g \mapsto g^{-1}$ must be a (nontrivial) automorphism, and it has order $2$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, if $G$ is abelian, is $\phi(g)=g^{-1}$ the only possible automorphism? I'm trying to figure out how the evenness of $|Aut(G)|$ can be deduced only by the fact that $G$ is abelian and the highest order an element is known.

Comment: @sequence: it is sometimes the only automorphism of even order (for example, when $G = C_3$).